# Get data from json Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have problem to get my data from json

I have a json file like

```
{
"users": [
    {
        "file_number": 1000,
        "name": "Sara (10)",
        "user_id": 130,
        "user_reference_number": 100,
        "log_out": {
            "user_id": 136,
            "name": "Anton (888)",
            "user_file_number": 78,
            "user_reference_number": 104,
            "supervisor": "Tom Hudson (876)",
            "date": "02/14/2014 10:00",
        },
        "log_in": [
            {
                "date": "03/20/2014 15:39",
                "user_monitor": "UBC (65)",
                "user_number": 2000,
```

I want to get my  "date": "02/14/2014 10:00" but I have problem to get it 
I can get my "name": "Anton (888)" but I don't know why I cannot get my date
I also can get my user_id 130

would you please help me in this implementation, here is my code

Thanks in advance!

```
  public void chooseUser(String userId) {
    Fragment fragment = new ListFragment();

    String userIdOfSelectedUniversity =       UniversityServer.getSharedInstance().usersData.getUsersAttribute(userId,Constants_JSON.USER_ID);
    UserData.UserDefinition userDefinitionOfSelectedUniversity = UniversityServer.getSharedInstance().usersData.getUserDefinition(Integer.parseInt(userIdOfSelectedUniversity));
    String userName = userDefinitionOfSelectedUniversity.name;

    String myDate = UniversityServer.getSharedInstance().usersData.getUsersAttribute(userId,Constants_JSON.DATE);


    Bundle args = new Bundle();
```

I can get my UserID

```
       args.putString(Constants.ARG_USER_DATE, userId);
```

I cannot get my detailDate

```
       args.putString(Constants.ARG_TRIP_DATE,detailDate);
```

I can get my UserName

```
    args.putString(Constants.ARG_USER_NAME,userName);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    MainActivity main = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    main.sendFragment(fragment);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried validating your JSON using a service such as http://jsonlint.com/ ?

Comment: @MarcusGabilheri yes Valid JSON

Comment: Can you post your logcat?

Comment: @MarcusGabilheri I will get java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null

Comment: @MarcusGabilheri in log I have detailDate="02/14/2014 10:00" but my program crash and said name == Null

Comment: @MarcusGabilheri Error is n't related to parsing since I can print it on log

Comment: Can you trace the variable "name" and see if has been correctly initialized and has a value?

Comment: can you put your full code here

Answer (score 0):

Which Date are you trying to get? I can only see date as a child of log_in and log_out, so if you want one of them, you will may need to reference them from their parent.

Something like:

```
UniversityServer.getSharedInstance().usersData.getUsersAttribute(userId,Constants_JSON.log_in).date;
```